# Determine route in multi route controller method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, controller

That defines multi route method in controller in Spring MVC

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/path", "/path2"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String MyMethod () {
  // Determine which route invoked the method
  return null;
}
```

Is there a way to determine which route invoked the method?

Appreciate your kind help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`HttpServletRequest`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) which has a method called `getRequestURL()` to retrieve the actual URL, allowing you to parse which path was used.

However, another possibility is using path variables instead:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{path}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String myMethod(@PathVariable String path) {
    // Do stuff with "path"
    return null;
}
```

In this case, the `path` variable will contain whatever you enter matching the path given in your `@RequestMapping`, in your case it would be `"path"` or `"path2"`. However, this will also allow other path variables as well (`"path3"` for example, ...), so you might want to validate it first before using.

Comment: 10x I should have figure it out. With path variable would be much simple and easier

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use HttpServletRequest:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/path.html", "/path2.html"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String MyMethod (HttpServletRequest request) {
  // Determine which route invoked the method
  String url = new String(request.getRequestURL());
  log.debug("URL: " + url); //use whatever you use to log
  return null;
}
```

Comment: 10x that was helpful